# lxc / docker wake on lan?

Tags: lxc, wake-on-lan, ethtool

Has anyone successfully implemented "wake on LAN" functionality in a linux container?

In my setup each client has his own container for a vpn, but I only want the container to "boot up" when the client connects to it. One idea I had is to use internal DNS to resolve the container, and start it when a DNS request is received. However it would be far simpler if there was some sort of "wake on lan" functionality I could use.

The closest I could find is lxc checkpointing, which is not yet implemented.

Comment: "Wake on LAN" is something else entirely. You are looking for [socket activation for containers](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activated-containers.html).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. If only I could tip you money. :) Thanks!!